# Is there a way to find multiline arguments in discord.command()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to build a discord bot that acts as a social media site along with a few more other functions. But I'm stuck on the posting command. There is no way (Or at least in my knowledge) that I can get multiline arguments from the discord bot user. Here's the function so far:

```py
@bot.command() 
async def post(ctx, theme, name, *description):
  sep = " "
  description1 = sep.join(description)
  if theme not in ['news', 'challenge', 'share', 'announcement', 'question', 'tutorial']:
    await ctx.send(f"Invalid theme: {theme}")
  else:
    with open("global.json", "r") as globe:
      dat = json.load(globe)
    with open(f"profiles/{ctx.author}.json", "r") as author:
      auth = json.load(author)
    with open(f"posts.json", "r") as post:
      posts = json.load(post)
    post_dict = {"name": name, "theme": theme, "desc": description1, "id": dat["postId"], "likes": [], "comments": []}
    posts.append(post_dict)
    auth["Posts"].append([name, dat["postId"]])
    dat['postId'] += 1
    with open("global.json", "w") as globe1:
      dat = json.dump(dat, globe1)
    with open(f"profiles/{ctx.author}.json", "w") as author1:
      auth = json.dump(auth, author1)
    with open(f"posts.json", "w") as post1:
      posts = json.dump(posts, post1)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(description=f"A {str(theme).title()} Post under the name of {name} has been created, {ctx.author}!", color=0x00ff00)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

The description accepts multi-word agruments, but not multi-line arguments. Is there a way it can accept multi-lines? Or any other way to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the command like this, and remove the `description1` entirely.  it will take anything after the name as description no matter what is it. [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)

```
@bot.command() 
async def post(ctx, theme, name, *,description):
```